# How to put italics in the title of a document using MLA13?

Tags: xetex

I am trying to put the title of a book in the title of my document using the MLA13 class. Unfortunately, every time it ignores my font family and size. Here is the code I am using:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mla13}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\firstname{First}
\lastname{Last}
\professor{Professor Professor}
\class{A Class}
\title{A Review of \textit{A Book}}
% \sources{bibliography.bib}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
    \makeheader

    This is the content of the paper.
\end{document}
```

The produced output looks like this:

[image: 1]

How do I change the italicized portion of the title so that it displays in the same font as the rest of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `mla13.sty` is completely and utterly wrong.

```
\newcommand*{\makeheader}{\begingroup
\rmfamily
\fontsize{12}{2}
\noindent \@firstname\ \@lastname\\
\@professor\\
\@class\\
\datef\@date
\begin{nospacecenter}
\@title
\end{nospacecenter}
\endgroup}
```

This makes no sense whatsoever to set the font size and not issuing `\selectfont`. What happens is that in

```
A Review of \textit{A Book}
```

the first three words are typeset in the current font size, independent of `\fontsize{12}{2}`; to the contrary, `\textit` issues `\selectfont`, so the setting of `\fontsize` enters into action.

The package's idea is probably to use a larger font size for the header, assuming a main font size of 10pt. But a baseline skip of 2pt is absurd.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mla13}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\patchcmd{\makeheader}{\fontsize{12}{2}}{\large}{}{}


\firstname{First}
\lastname{Last}
\professor{Professor Professor}
\class{A Class}
\title{A Review of \textit{A Book}}
% \sources{bibliography.bib}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
    \makeheader

    This is the content of the paper.
\end{document}
```

If you don't want a larger font size for the header, then remove `\large` as suggested by Alan Munn.

[image]